# PHP Cookies (If Else)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Buy Product</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="/itemlist.php"><img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/promotion-vector-stamp-isolated-white-37908603.jpg" style="height:400px; width:450px;"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
      setcookie("Logged");

  });

</script>
```

Working Link Below

> https://jsbin.com/vabujuboqo/

What i wanted:

> When running through the site , the page will pop-up modal and add
>   cookies "Logged", Once customer refresh the page it won't show the
>   pop-up modal again . But when user restart browser , the pop-up modal
>   will triggered again. ( as when i setcookie didn't specific date so it
>   will delete "Logged" cookies when browser is closed/restarted

What is the problem right now

> Whenever i restart the page , the pop-up modal will keep on "pop-up" ,
>   trying to make it pop-up once per browser session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `setcookie`, a PHP function, in JavaScript (you are calling the function in the browser). You can set and get the cookie via JavaScript using something like this:

```
<script>

// This function will set a cookie with expiration after days
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    const d = new Date;
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000*days)
    document.cookie = `${name}=${value};path=/;expires=${d.toGMTString()}`;
}

// This function will retrieve an existing cookie so you can check its existence
function getCookie(name) {
    const v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return v ? v[2] : null;
}

setCookie('Logged', '1')
console.log(getCookie('Logged')) // 1

</script>
```

So you could check if the cookie exists and then, if not exists, set it.